# Find which program caused a core dump file

Tags: linux, debugging, ubuntu, coredump

I've been going through intense program/package installation recently, so I can't tell for sure which of the newly installed programs (or old programs) caused the appearance of a `core` file in my home folder. It's a server, so I better find out any possible sources of instability on the machine.

Comment: On FreeBSD this is work for me, `dmesg | tail -n 20`

Comment: @SIFE that certainly works if it happened very recently.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can simply use the `file` program to identify them:

E.g

```
# file /var/core/core
/var/core/core:     ELF 64-bit MSB core file SPARCV9 Version 1, from 'crs_stat.bin'
```

Comment: Sometimes I have had core files that for whatever reason "file" cannot identify -- in those cases, the fact that the last line of the output of strings on the corefile often contains the path to the executable can help.  e.g. "strings /path/to/corefile | tail -n 1" often works, or look at the last few lines.

Comment: @jsegal: Good find, but I needed `strings core | grep ^/ | tail -1` when `find` told me: `too many program header sections`.

Comment: I am not sure I have understood, ELF 64-bit does not tell which binary generated the core dump?

Comment: Indeed, `file` fails miserably for me: my executable is launched with a shell wrapper, with a very long command line. `file` fails to print the meaningful part of it.

Answer (score 7):

Often using the file program on the core file will show the errant executable, as explained by @Benj in the accepted answer (code from Benj's answer):

```
# file /var/core/core
/var/core/core:     ELF 64-bit MSB core file SPARCV9 Version 1, from 'crs_stat.bin'
```

However, sometimes you may get a complaint about "too many program header sections":

```
core.some-lib.nnnn.nnnn: ELF 64-bit LSB  core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), too many program header sections (1850)
```

In this case, you can try some alternatives:

- Tail the last several strings of the corefile (the app was about 25 back for me): `strings core.some-lib.nnnn.nnnn | tail -50`
- Use gdb itself: `gdb -c core.some-lib.nnnn.nnnn` This will often tell you something like this: `Core was generated by '/usr/local/bin/some-executable'`

Answer (score -1):

you can navigate to the directory where the core.pid is and run gdb core core.pid