# linux: is there a way to find out which process generated a core file?

Tags: linux, process, gdb, coredump

I've got some core dump files generated in my system, but the suffix for these core files only has a timestamp, no process ID information.

So it there any process ID related information inside a core file, so that I can know it from gdb or other tools?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308922/find-which-program-caused-a-core-dump-file

Comment: @Randolf No, this question is about how to get the *process id* of the process that generated the core file, while that other question is about which *program* generated the core file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So it there any process id related information inside core files

Definitely.

In the `core` file, there is a set of ELF notes. The note you are looking for is of type `NT_PRPSINFO`, and it contains (among other things) `pr_pid` that you want:

```
typedef struct prpsinfo {       /* Information about process                 */
  unsigned char  pr_state;      /* Numeric process state                     */
  char           pr_sname;      /* Char for pr_state                         */
  unsigned char  pr_zomb;       /* Zombie                                    */
  signed char    pr_nice;       /* Nice val                                  */
  unsigned long  pr_flag;       /* Flags                                     */
  uint32_t       pr_uid;        /* User ID                                   */
  uint32_t       pr_gid;        /* Group ID                                  */

  pid_t          pr_pid;        /* Process ID                                */
  pid_t          pr_ppid;       /* Parent's process ID                       */
  pid_t          pr_pgrp;       /* Group ID                                  */
  pid_t          pr_sid;        /* Session ID                                */
  char           pr_fname[16];  /* Filename of executable                    */
  char           pr_psargs[80]; /* Initial part of arg list                  */

} prpsinfo;
```

The question is: which tool(s) can find and decode this note. Try `eu-readelf` from [elfutils](https://sourceware.org/elfutils/).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I did a `eu-readelf --all core.11234` and a few lines down I got:`
  CORE                 136  PRPSINFO
    state: 0, sname: R, zomb: 0, nice: 4, flag: 0x0000000000402440
    uid: 5000, gid: 492600, pid: 11869, ppid: 11804, pgrp: 11487`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the "file" command.

```
file <core_file>
```

That should tell you what executable/command caused the core to dump.  Let me know if that's not what you needed.

Comment: The question is about *process id*, and this answer doesn't answer that.

Comment: This question was marked as a possible duplicate by someone.  If you go to that other question you will see it's basically the same answer I gave.  I wasn't the only one who interpreted this question in this way.